# time limit in Gravity Forms

Tags: wordpress, forms, gravity-forms-plugin

I manage a time limit for gravity form with this piece of code:

```
<script>
function move() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");   
  var width = 0;
  var sanie = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 500);
  function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
      document.getElementById("gform_9").submit();
    } else {
      sanie+=0.5;     
      if(sanie % 1 == 0){elem.innerHTML = Math.floor(sanie/60) + " : " + sanie % 60}
      if(sanie % 10 == 0){width++;elem.style.width = width + '%';}
    }
  }
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  move();
});
</script>
<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar">0 : 0</div>
</div>
[gravityform id="9" title="true" description="true"]
```

My form is multipage and when time limit is exceeded each page goes to next. Until on last page form is submitted. The problem is that the time limit for all pages is the same. How can I set time limit for each page individually?

Comment: Why not pass the view that the user is on to the form. Once you have the view you can do an if statement to change the time on your form.

Comment: could you give a simple example?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check what page the user is on then change the form accordingly

```
  if ( document.URL.contains("homepage.aspx") ) {
    //Change time of form here.
  }else if ( document.URL.contains("someotherpage.aspx") ) {
    //A different page change form time here
  }
}
```

document.URL will get you the current url the user is on. .contains checks to see if it does contain the URL you want.